# IBM bluemix course 3 - deploy chaincode v2.0

Tags: json, post, github, ibm-cloud, blockchain

I am learning blockchain through IBM's blockchain course 3. When I try to deploy the chaincode it picks up the master code instead of the version 2.0. I saw a related [post](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode#deploying-the-chaincode) but it did not help.

Complete JSON:

```js
 {
     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     "method": "deploy",
     "params": {
         "type": 1,
         "chaincodeID": {
             "path": "https://github.com/dithmarschen96/learn-chaincode.v2/start"
         },
         "ctorMsg": {
             "function": "init",
             "args": [
                 "hi there"
             ]
         },
         "secureContext": "user_type1_1"
     },
     "id": 1
 }
```

And the error message (note: it says could not read user name but if I remove ".v2" in the path it works with the same user name).

```
"code": -32001,
"message": "Deployment failure",
"data": "Error when deploying chaincode: Error getting chaincode package bytes: Error getting code 'go get' failed with error: \"exit status 1\"\n# cd .; git clone https://github.com/dithmarschen96/learn-chaincode.v2 /opt/gopath/_usercode_/557323755/src/github.com/dithmarschen96/learn-chaincode.v2\nCloning into '/opt/gopath/_usercode_/557323755/src/github.com/dithmarschen96/learn-chaincode.v2'...\nfatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address\npackage github.com/dithmarschen96/learn-chaincode.v2/start: exit status 128\n"
```

If I remove ".v2" in the path it works fine but I get the master and not the branch.

How do I reference the version 2 in JSON for the post call?

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the doc for the course:

Tip: You can use gopkg.in to provide a URL for the chaincode deploy that uses a GitHub branch
version:
http://gopkg.in//learn-chaincode.v2/finished